# Write a program with the smallest width

Tags: code-challenge, kolmogorov-complexity, hello-world

Print or return the following text:

```
Hello world! The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.
```

However, your submission will not be scored in bytes. Instead, primarily it will be scored by the width in pixels of the program when written in Arial in a 12pt font. In particular, the score is:

$$ (\text{visual width in px}) + \frac{1}{1000}(\text{length in characters})$$

Since there might be slight differences based on platform, OS etc the following program will be used to judge your score:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc7NToQwEADgO08xnqDRbQsmevLAxUiyB2O8GWO6MEC1MLWUZdmXx8IaEy@Tycw3P3b2LfW3S/5S5Ht4gFiQ9aJGo0/C6MNvtsVdJtM7Lu95mu1cmYqhVQ4viHo/iNxpZbj3dbzUjjp4LvagO0vOQ9GpBh@DilYazvwVuHcj@tlisn1wA2nGopIqDIgs9olk3KGqEhYd9TAq8zHpyrehu27iDfpBnzFZJ9ibfI@s071P/tFrMGHPJkBAKqXkki3LRcZPaAzBRM5UV/DaInyPuvyCg6OpDzdO8Dl2dgA6ogMFRp1nqKjhMfsB)

#### Rules

- Standard I/O rules apply.
- A single trailing newline is optionally permitted in the output. No other variation is permitted.
- Lowest score as calculated by the above program wins.
- Note that the measure of visual width used ignores newlines. As far as I can tell, you can never reduce the score of your program by adding characters.

Comment: Something seems wrong with [visual width](https://tio.run/##zVA9T8MwEN3vVxiWxip1nCLBxNAFUakDQmxRRdPGaVycODju558vL6FUjQTMDL68d/fu3V2qvc9teXscvYxHE/bAeqGtfJgpo3eh0fMTauNgKKM7Ie9FNBy4RRTWeeLUl8iWvg5HTidGeJ/1jpmzBXseT5guKus8GxfJUj1CRY0UY84J4d1a@X2lgnaDGxYNOS1sqiCylSoDyYVTSRpw2uh6nZi3rU59jmrjJJbK1/qggqaDx3JKldOlDy6l/Icc6zMD77aLhSySUgrJj8eYphTTjBK8mCKwPpA/s6/qgiyVVCPvaA3mwV2rmSF72Vl1mOkw/euMAHhGvPVbdVT2D4ey49Bcwk9e3/tabKBIIFpaonJNT@Cm5Yy27RWGUroCe6UcNUYfuFDD4R14jrqFrgTOgHb4rlAvcGcNbGmDHgeU4BnEA@2B0naewDz@L/8SB@Kf)?

Comment: @Bubbler I think the width is calculated assuming all on one line, looks like chars <32 score 9. Although it's implicit in the scoring mechanism I'll clarify in the description. I don't mind this as I'm pretty sure there's already a challenge using column width for scoring

Comment: (So sad that Mongolian script is rendered left to right but not top to bottom.)

Comment: "As far as I can tell, you can never reduce the score of your program by adding characters". If you try `A`, the width is 10. Now try `A\u200b` (append a zero-width space), strangely it becomes 9.

Comment: *Note that the measure of visual width used ignores newlines* You sure about that? It seems like a [newline has a width of 9](https://tio.run/##Tc69DoIwEADgvU/RjTbRFjDRyYHFhITBuBpjKhzQpNCmHCq@PAIa43K53H334wasbbsZk1OaZHRPA2kdyhKMfkqjb99sies4jLYi3IkoXvs8kl2tPHyQbbGTidfKCMQyGEtvG3pMM6obZz3StFEVHCZFZjqd@RUE@h5wcMCWD1Y0ijnJbQETsg5aFnLhQRWMk7vuemWuD11gPXXnTaIC7PQL2DzBz@GFOK9bZP@UjyN5Aw)

Comment: Based on @DJMcMayhem's comment, I think you probably meant to use [`getsize_multiline` instead](https://tio.run/##TY5Bi8IwEIXv@RW5mYAmbRf05KEgC4UeZP@AZO3UDqRJmE5X3T/fbVVk5zA8eN@bN@nOXQwfU/lVlbXcy5WNiW0LHm/W4/dLPfamyPKtyXYmLzZ0zu3QOYInFAMPtiR03jC3q6ml2MtjVUvsUySWVe8u8DlT66c8kLuKJTU3vj3DNALfE6jHM2uZF1qcYwMzFBMElWlD4BqlxQ8Oo/OnKzbcze5yyVyAB/yFUz96Ro8B1JLVIhEGVv8TeprEMn8).

Comment: we should do this challenge with height too

Answer (score 31):

## [Zalgo](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Zalgo), score <s>5.221</s> 0.222

```
​̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̝̐̈̄̐̅̆̐̌̆̐̌̆̐̏̆̐̀̂̐̇̇̐̏̆̐̂̇̐̌̆̐̄̆̐́̂̐̀̂̐̄̅̐̈̆̐̅̆̐̀̂̐́̇̐̅̇̐̉̆̐̃̆̐̋̆̐̀̂̐̂̆̐̂̇̐̏̆̐̇̇̐̎̆̐̀̂̐̆̆̐̏̆̐̈̇̐̀̂̐̊̆̐̅̇̐̍̆̐̀̇̐̃̇̐̀̂̐̏̆̐̆̇̐̅̆̐̂̇̐̀̂̐́̆̐̀̂̐̌̆̐́̆̐̊̇̐̉̇̐̀̂̐̄̆̐̏̆̐̇̆̐̎̂​
```

[Score this online!](https://tio.run/##vZHBTsIwHMbve4re2KJ0HSZ68rCLCQkH49UYM6FAk7EuXVHxBBMKCqIv4BvtKXyR2f07WH0B0@RL8@@v3/c1TWdyzJOzMrzphj10iVo@T6U/pDF79mP2UO9A2x0SnGNygYNOW/QDPxtHghqIJzLzQ8GiGEs5bJVDwSfouttDbJJyIVF3Eo3olaacCtUxxwGWYkrlLKUuNDhFQcdz@nxANcRTmrjEw4JGA9dzHlk2jeL7JzaQY31aOeERlRl7oW51w7sld04qWCLdP@gJirUPEMhHASEEE68sf@bb4vtf11exKZZaV4XSurP0E3Re5FrXeh0mOewNswRdAGPIpXaqPNXR08wXcGsF@gbzV9CtxeSWv8kyuXuLUVa3DZya@XudWE0@an4NKQ1jbqm6SZN1aNik7Op3KXA2ndfWG5XVUEHDXH/dLw)

I think I found the <s>perfect</s> **uberperfect** language! Tested with the [official interpreter](https://github.com/shortc1rcuit/zalgo) locally. Now also uses dingledooper's observation that zalgo surrounded by two `\u200b`s has width zero. Luckily (and surprisingly) `\u200b` is not considered as a whitespace in the interpreter (which uses Rust's `char.is_whitespace`).

Script to generate the source:

```python
s = 'Hello world! The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.'
ans = '\u200b'
ans += '\u031d' * len(s)
for c in s:
    d = ord(c)
    ans += '\u0310' + chr(0x300 + d % 16) + chr(0x300 + d // 16)
print(ans + '\u200b', end='')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY5BDoIwFET3nGJcmIIYKZK4MGHvAVy6AVoErf3YgoCXR6yJifGv5k3yJr8Z24p0Mk0WKdhBKkXoySixwLGSuHd1cUVuqNcoacCluzUW9JAGGVT2HCHovGFepp1/6rac5x8MHfMkFgwrKKl9G3glGRSoNezew3xitsgIvwgc/nicIURRGZ8PCedzFlgi3gV/bRS9a68xtW59N/H9ZA2pRcpYME0v)

Comment: `print(ans, end='\u200b')` saves ... sorry, I couldn't help myself there.

Answer (score 30):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 125.833 score

```py
ᵉᵛªˡ(ᵇʸᵗᵉſ(ᵐªᵖ(ˡᵉⁿ,'​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​'.ſᵖˡᵢᵗ('‌'))))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=7dyhDoJQFIDhxwE3NRl8AJ_FmdSgwabJOQ0mCBRw00C_m42NjSJvYLs8idepb-DwnOvv_iIF-A7jJm5yma8Wk9k0Tc_Lxbg3vI8G1uysScq8zkJrtrerNbE7VBXu37HMrYnCOnMHmk3RDZr1nr7a4dcX4GvAoickMH3lbe3UHj9CHt8aYpKDEUaBteDJyNoJZzxVBCyMvnKxnnL7YoNOoBhDQVVjCKOHlZZYyOQEFLAqwhNndbHSyQw0PJXGK0V-ACKsJSQhVRTLn7rwBFlgiOmFZXZClBgEjCj5GuCeaTNQuPBUlyi3v_jyN-hXhTXRc_-PkzVxGLjLCTru99o85L2HyGcvkQc) *or* [Score this online!](https://tio.run/##7dw/T8JAGMfxnVdxW9sI/YOJTg4sJiQMxtUYU@GAJqVt2kPFSSdjZHCCwQlH9yZuJCQs8irKG8EDjYm7C/IlvxC4Pi3t52l7U0kGqhtH@6vaab3WEEfCcOJEOW0ZBjdOGFx@f9q8V6qud2C7h7ZXraRNz8m6fiq/iuJIZU4tDfzQVqptrNpp3BMn9YYIekmcKlHv@R15rKtK61L9Mz8Dtkr7Ug0SaW72oCy8qlVqxi2pi@JERqZr2an0W6ZVugqyvh9eXAct1dVL11uyO1Jlwa0012tYZ@55KUmDSJm/SvdEqLezqRCO8FzXtV1rtSryxyJ/mb0tJmaRP3y8F/lYD82n@tvz7K3IR@ZiogeW99Oysbx7In@aIQjAogcm2ULeIacQh4YYjDCS7fGkZVwaeBJgYfz3XMynHD50iNEUTnWECXpYMZERoIDFk@DMTEdfCJ5Q000AEUaSQMr0hzOeICNGuEXTCBoBI0qAE27XdITguctuO/Hkr2HPp0U@Wv//x2uRj01D745h6dcn)

#### Explanation

Through some experimentation, I found that `\u200a` (zero width space) takes up **zero** pixels. In addition, as kindly pointed out by [Mukundan314](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/91267/mukundan314), `\u200c` seems to use up zero pixels as well, though only when surrounded by `\u200a`. Using this fact, I created an algorithm to encode any string using only the characters `\u200c` and `\u200a`. The algorithm works by encoding each character as a string of `\u200c`s whose size is the value of its unicode codepoint. Then, they are joined together by `\u200a`.

Then, decoding it is simply a matter of splitting the string by the `\u200c` delimiter, mapping each element to its length, and converting it back into a string using the `bytes` builtin:

```py
bytes(map(len,'...'.split('\u200c')))
```

In the implementation, the strange-looking unicode characters are converted to ASCII due to Python's [implicit NFKC normalization of identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html), which help slightly shorten the pixel width.

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 139.097 score

*-0.002 score thanks to @Neil, who noticed that the `\u200b`s are apparently unnecessary here.*

```
ᵉᵛªˡ(ᵇʸᵗᵉſ(ºʳᵈ(ˡ)%126for ˡ in'⁮ّۘ⁬ֲٍ֑ۚ︠⁪⁪⁭᷿̔⁭ۘ⁪ٌٍِ͈̔̔̕⁯ًّۛٓ̔ﱢۘ⁭᷿⁬َ̔⁭ْͬ̔ۛ⁫⁮ۙ̔⁭ٍ᷾ۘ̔ﱡ̔⁪ﱡٌ۠۟̔⁭ُ‬֑︡'))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3zz3c2vlw6-xDq04v1Hi4tf3UjodbpwOFju7XOLTr1OaHWzs0Ti_UVDU0MkvLL1I4vVAhM0_9UeO62zNuTnzUuOb2rPc7FlybeG3Tzd5HjavAaO2ZKQ-37wfSt2cA-Td7zkw9M-Vsx80JN3vPTHnUuP727JsTb3bfnHxmyvuNi0BK1oJVrzkz5WYfkHMWxJh0e_ajxtUgW2aC9ABV7LvZe3sGSMtCkMAqIH17we35QKU9QOmb_Y8a1lyb-H7HQnVNTYivoJ6DeRIA)

An alternative solution, which although longer, may port better to other languages. The idea here is that any string of accent characters embedded between two `\u200b`s has a pixel width of zero.

Comment: [125.833](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=7dyhDoJQFIDhxwE3NRl8AJ_FmdSgwabJOQ0mCBRw00C_m42NjSJvYLs8idepb-DwnOvv_iIF-A7jJm5yma8Wk9k0Tc_Lxbg3vI8G1uysScq8zkJrtrerNbE7VBXu37HMrYnCOnMHmk3RDZr1nr7a4dcX4GvAoickMH3lbe3UHj9CHt8aYpKDEUaBteDJyNoJZzxVBCyMvnKxnnL7YoNOoBhDQVVjCKOHlZZYyOQEFLAqwhNndbHSyQw0PJXGK0V-ACKsJSQhVRTLn7rwBFlgiOmFZXZClBgEjCj5GuCeaTNQuPBUlyi3v_jyN-hXhTXRc_-PkzVxGLjLCTru99o85L2HyGcvkQc) by using `\u200c` (has 0 width if surrounded by chars) instead of `\u200a`

Comment: @Mukundan314 Wow! I've been assuming that `\u200a` only occupies one pixel width (which is the case by itself), but doesn't seem to be the case when I used it with `\u200a`. Thanks again for the substantial byte save :)

Comment: Your last solution doesn't need the `\u002b`s saving `0.002` off the score.

Comment: This has to be a bug ...

Answer (score 7):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), score <s>49.089</s> <s>27.235</s> 27.107

```
⍘⍘̔̆́̐̐̑̊̓̇̂̐̇̋̒́̒̎̏̌́̄̐́̉̌̇̀̍̌̌̓̒̊̋̎́̄̎̅̍̃̂̒̃̂̉̏̑̈̋̄̎̋̂̂̃̋̋̍̎̀̈̍̀̆̇̐́̐̒́̑̄̑̎̒̌̎̑̐̔̄¦̀́̂̃̄̅̆̇̈̉̊̋̌̍̎̏̐̑̒̓̔γ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY5LDsIgEIbP2nTjwsTEE7QV@xBoAbvwBF7AG7j@00N4EfwgkGH4XzPtqbm2l@ac88@/uNo1qlfgRD301KSBfpJVAk9atcnRGdBeC/2kTp7XoU54LJrCr7qD3/CnWhecUTN84SzIAG45nn8H46kjeaFuUOZFtBE2kb7SBfYz3ze6vroNM4pjJr1MdjVrq9sn9tmPT85/) No verbose version because the deverbosifier extraneously quotes the strings, which is longer than using the `¦` separator. Explanation: Converts a string from base `\u0300-\u0314` and then into base  `-~` (printable ASCII).

```
  ̔̆́̐̐̑̊̓̇̂̐̇̋̒́̒̎̏̌́̄̐́̉̌̇̀̍̌̌̓̒̊̋̎́̄̎̅̍̃̂̒̃̂̉̏̑̈̋̄̎̋̂̂̃̋̋̍̎̀̈̍̀̆̇̐́̐̒́̑̄̑̎̒̌̎̑̐̔̄      Literal string of \u0300-\u0314 characters
 ⍘      Convert from base
   ̀́̂̃̄̅̆̇̈̉̊̋̌̍̎̏̐̑̒̓̔     Literal string `\u0300-\u0314`
⍘       Convert to base
   γ    Predefined variable printable ASCII
        Implicitly print
```

Comment: I think you mean `\u200b\u200c\u200d`? `\u002b\u002c\u002d` is `+,-`.

Comment: @Bubbler I did, but I'm using different characters now because I was able to shave `0.128` off my score this way.

Comment: Verbose version using the newer version of Charcoal on ATO: [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZVLLCsIwEAS_pORkQSFpo1a8-QWCR_WQpFYFUejDH_HopQdFv8mvUTcLGexl2E62s7OT3F5ub0p3Nse2fTR1MczeveuiPJzq_txU22X9LXdYinUjU6V_KMeEihgJSIw0VKdUTwiT0MOMJSYBHV9vCQtCF06lBgXPTKHHa_rTHHgXnLC-CdN5FugzMwKdFPwn_wx7KGD3DPRR08JfqGMBc-iXoJYDMw77YhqcP-aJuamgzD0OGFTwnrUYRAKmqo5vDUmBJ3Y87WTtOhsW_-_GO-Pb0iIeRLs4nt0r6yp-oc-VGF6OYsOfHw)

Answer (score 5):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), score 64.584

```
`0:`c$#'"‌"\"​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​"
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJzt2MEJwkAQhtFeVsGrZ2vxELAR70mVVqIlKMSZyc6Dh0cXv/0JxOV6Wx7n02W8ntu4fz7XnWz7fRV1Os99XMqJhyNRn/Ipdz39Q4aGvpmZKWYlUj6M1DoXIVGf5pHnxpxlvZHUlqiCDq/kWT8T5QUvKCxRqwed4UlEHR1ejcHeCGZyxLO6golcCikMb+LOLlci0tlYtURuhH+zMfFpyPYkogL/4zErS+MH4w2v5O4F) or [Score this online!](https://tio.run/##7ZhBS8MwHEfv/RRhCmvRpekEBcHDLsJgB/Gq4uqWbYGuKWmmzpN3@yn9IrXbRDx4ksFkPniEkv6TlJdfc0ix9DObn9S9635vIC5EO7aFjyc6M89xZh4@n9Ztp6uSU6nOZNLtuFESl7PU6U2RzX0Z95xJM@n9pF1PnJ2Lq/5AmHlhnRf9eTrVl01VsCptlvnqkN4ttF8WOlx/wbFIulEwsmPdFNlC56GKpNPpOIyCR1Mu0uz@yYz9rHm7mklOtS/Niw5XI6IbdRcUzuQ@/F4a/dAnjkTWzL0eJWKRKKWkiup6qM6Ho8ODduv9tWrdNu3blqi2NxX8Hc/7vRy5RRHmd77XFXmGf/nzEsVdKcI85y2eUQT76rzau7VIL2cFipDMzQNgHuEo4qAjeCgCwkbIgZwDEDkgdShiU4DTAM9sLvkHMoYidgSINCAfyB6KALjHAyBp8HtaHw)

A port of dingledooper's answer to K. Uses `\u200b` as the "word" character and `\u200c` as the separator. The only difference is that "length" `#` counts each "space" character as 3 bytes, so I had to do a little calculation so that `(word length in characters) * 3 % 256 == output character`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, Score 41.09

```
`​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​`\‌/vLC
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJzIiwiIiwiYOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAjOKAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi+KAi2BcXOKAjC92TEMiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Port of dingledooper's answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), score: 494.078 (78 bytes)

```
"He
llo
 wo
rld
! T
he 
qui
ck 
bro
wn 
fox
 ju
mps
 ov
er 
a l
azy
 do
g.
"ṇc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHBGcFAFIXR/V/FlQIsVKEAK7vJZCTi8RhfRDSgJuWo5OWctqY8LOb9LqLZF8wczU61jo0ODEU8pjP5ItrqzDdx8jcaJ673J/IXpYokI30W1Dn9lub/@@aIOK4)

Not as competitive as the rest, but the program contains the expected string with no specific encoding.

#### Explanation

`"ṇc` ends a string, splits it on linebreaks into a list of strings, and then concatenates it back into a single string with no linebreaks.

We then split the string into chunks of at most 3 chars with linebreaks, as Brachylog supports inline multi-line strings.

Comment: The scoring function [doesn't quite work like you imagine](https://tio.run/##VY7BToQwEIbvPMW4l4XotgUTPXngYiTZgzHejDFdOkC1MLWUZdmXx4LGZC@TyfzffDN28g11t3P@UuR7eIAtJ@t5hUafuNGHv26tu0ykd0zcszTbuTLlfSMd/kLU@Z7nTkvDvK@2c@WohediD7q15DwUrazxMVDRgoYz/wPm3YB@shivH9xAmiVRSQoDRBa7WCTMoVRxEh11P0jzMWrlm5AuJlaj7/UZ42UjeRPvkXW68/EFeg0meFYCOKRCCCaSed48oTEEIzmjruC1QfgedPkFB0djF@wn@Bxa2wMd0YEEI88TKKrZ5gc).

Comment: @Bubbler Well, this challenge makes no sense whatsoever then.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, score 261.096

```
FromCharacterCode[ToCharacterCode@"̨͌͌ͅ͏̀͗͏̴͈͕͉͒͌̈́́̀̀͑̓͋̀͂͒ͅ͏͎͗̀͆͏͕͍͓̀͊͐̀͘͏͖͚͙͒̀́̀͌́̀̈́ͅ͏͇̎"-736]
```

[View it on Wolfram Cloud!](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/3eca615e-a692-4acf-a5dd-4f7636397a8f)

[Score it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/fSsMwFMbv@xRhN2vRpWkH25XgGAwKuxDxbgypa7YFuqakmTqvNt3876oT/z6BD@Bj9DxTPasijEDyy/m@8@UknuihjKp5Y99rtMkOKdsy1nafh@LUDsXRHxV7xWVOjbI6ddyK6jl2MvQV/zXJSCd2Qwk/pFr3y3lfyRHZ89pEjGKpNPFG/oC30GWsrfjMf4FqNeZ6EnOzmGCbOK5l9GTA0SRjHpnMoor7gWkZxyIZ@@HhiQj0ENV1Eh1wnYgzbq47rA7rGrESkTY3rFskxJzCQWziMMYos/K8hTM28Qt@T3PVRLVzIDfuu6XsCxZwjyvNpvAGKayQ59ksm2bfcA0LrD7BC9zABdwhn6Oeom@JfIn0juct6g/wCM/IKbxi3goJEzBpBp/wgTRH5Spblir1aq37Aw)

Answer (score 1):

### Pascal, 495.092

```pascal
program i(output);begin write('Hello world! The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.')end.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), score 40.062

```
’̨͌͌ͅ͏̀͗͏̴͈͕͉͒͌̈́́̀̀͑̓͋̀͂͒ͅ͏͎͗̀͆͏͕͍͓̀͊͐̀͘͏͖͚͙͒̀́̀͌́̀̈́ͅ͏͇̎’ÇŽ2ã-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dc0xDoJAEIXhE9F4I0wsrCi8wCIgKsoKBhRbGg5ga0Xs5l2Ciyx/tpgv8yZvk0O83e9CWNxgkwrdeN6cXvJqcW6pOfvqrIJto04XZarwkdxzV@MTejOv5Hc99MRePX0tooGmVB8NKCcprebDufz/NvMYhbAC) Outputs as a list of byte values.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), score <s>30.062</s> [29.061](https://tio.run/##VY7LSgMxFIb38xShLjqDNsmMoCsX3QiFLsStiIxtpg1MJyGTqnXVauvdjla8rlz6AL6FOc80nlYRJJB8nP/Ln@iB7apstaxvN@pNskGqTGnLEpHKI5bK/V9a7LWIh2uUr9MwqplWyPJubMSPpDKbs7qRcUqtTaplYlSPbDWaRPa0MpY0enFHbKLlzVV85m9ArekLO9DCX/xghYRR4LVUW6CktMh8HlAj4rYfeAcy78fp3qFs2y6m8ybaETaXx8Kf3wh2@K6njcys/09dJin2LAzCSMg5pzwoy4r7gAnc4CrcEJ6hgBny2I3c0H3CBUxweg@PcAmncI18gnmB3hT5DOkFzyvMb@EOHpALeMK@GRI2YNMI3uAVaYzJuZtWWrWlr/dv)

```
"̨͌͌ͅ͏̀͗͏̴͈͕͉͒͌̈́́̀̀͑̓͋̀͂͒ͅ͏͎͗̀͆͏͕͍͓̀͊͐̀͘͏͖͚͙͒̀́̀͌́̀̈́ͅ͏͇̎"c-#ˠ
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=Ilx1MDMyOFx1MDM0NVx1MDM0Y1x1MDM0Y1x1MDM0Zlx1MDMwMFx1MDM1N1x1MDM0Zlx1MDM1Mlx1MDM0Y1x1MDM0NFx1MDMwMVx1MDMwMFx1MDMzNFx1MDM0OFx1MDM0NVx1MDMwMFx1MDM1MVx1MDM1NVx1MDM0OVx1MDM0M1x1MDM0Ylx1MDMwMFx1MDM0Mlx1MDM1Mlx1MDM0Zlx1MDM1N1x1MDM0ZVx1MDMwMFx1MDM0Nlx1MDM0Zlx1MDM1OFx1MDMwMFx1MDM0YVx1MDM1NVx1MDM0ZFx1MDM1MFx1MDM1M1x1MDMwMFx1MDM0Zlx1MDM1Nlx1MDM0NVx1MDM1Mlx1MDMwMFx1MDM0MVx1MDMwMFx1MDM0Y1x1MDM0MVx1MDM1YVx1MDM1OVx1MDMwMFx1MDM0NFx1MDM0Zlx1MDM0N1x1MDMwZSJjLSNcdTAyZTA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), score 58.092

```
smCldc"​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​"\‌
```

[Try it here!](https://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=smCldc%22%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%22%5C%E2%80%8C&debug=0)

[Score it online!](https://tio.run/##7dVPS4RAGMfxu69i2MsqteNoUKcOSxAIe4iuFWHruDugjoyz1XbqXq@yN2JqEfQOYvvCDxF9/DOfR2favd/a5qRfXmfLlTgX89i2Pi51ZZ7jyjx8703bRaqSU6nOZJIu3DqJu23u9FeRbXwXL53JK@l9Oe9LZ2txla2EqVvrvMjqfKMvh6pgLB0e83NAerfTft/qcHqDY5GkUbC2hR6KbKubUEXS6bwIo@DRdLu8un8yhd8OZ8c7yY32nXnR4XhFdKPugtaZxoe/So9ENdxnqhCxSJRSUkV939UXVbGefby@HWjeD3doiMEII/lrnrSMXwNPAiyMB8/FesrwoUOMpvCpI0zQw4qFjAAFLJ4EZ1Y6@kLwhJpuAogwkgRSlj@c8QQZMcIUTSNoBIwoAU6YrukIwfP/us1uh9f5BA)

Near literal translation of [dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546/dingledooper)'s [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251553/78186).